# Message "No Audio Output Device is Installed" - but there is

Tags: audio, windows-server-2008-r2, drivers

I have a Asus P8Z68-V board with onboard sound (Realtek HD). The driver obviously is installed, at least that's what the device manager says at the node `Sound, video and game controllers`. I have the entry `High Definition Audio Device` and since I have a 2nd gen Core i5, there is also an HDMI port with integrated audio, which is listed as Intel(R) Display Audio`. Both devices are working properly, at least that's what the property dialog says about both.

After the first message that the Audio Service is not running, I set the `Windows Audio` service's start mode to automatic and also started it.

Now the icon in the tray still is red and says `No Audio Output Device is installed`. But I definetly can tell that there IS an audio device installed. What can I do to make my Windows Server 2008 R2 recognize the audio devices?

Comment: Have you tried updating/re-installing th Realtek Drivers?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I have an Acer Aspire 4520, and I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @aliensurfer same here now.. did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating/re-installing the Realtek Drivers?

Since there are no 'official' Windows 2008 R2 drivers for that Desktop board, then aim to use the Windows 7 driver(s) and hope they work. :)

You have a couple options to try to get the latest driver:

- [From Asus.](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V/#download)
- [From Realtek.](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#1)